# Is it possible to receive multiple bounties for same question?

Tags: bug, bounty

I have recently replied to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254679/print-pdf-in-firefox/33824109#33824109) on stackoverflow with a bounty of 50 reputation.

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount.

This was the case and I received 25 reputation. However, the following happened:

1. my solution resulted in another problem
2. creator edited the question
3. creator set another bounty of 100 reputation on the question
4. I edited my answer and it got accepted

This time my answer was accepted. According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty I should earn the full bounty of 100 reputation.

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

I did not receive any reputation. Is this intended or is this a bug? Do I miss something?

Comment: "... and the question owner accepts an answer **posted during the bounty period** ..."

Comment: Oh, so I would need to post another answer instead of editing it. (since the question completely changed). Too bad.

Comment: I don't know the nature of the JS code there, but just the fact that the op edited a troubleshooting question's MCVE after multiple elaborate answers were provided seems really uncool (bad!).

Comment: Note that this does not mean you should post another answer. You should roll back the edit the OP made to their question, or ask the user to ask a separate question, optionally referring to their original question. They should not be editing questions and changing the question.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I was kind of confused on what to do. Since my answer did not even match with the question anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key problem here is that your answer was not posted *after* the bounty was started.  From the same how bounties work page (emphasis mine):

> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an **answer posted during the bounty period**, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.,

Because you only edited an existing answer, your answer does not qualify for auto-awarding, even though the OP started the bounty and also accepted your answer.

As for your title question, you can receive multiple bounties for the same answer.  According to this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/406949/answers-awarded-multiple-bounties), it's happened 254 times as of December 6, 2015.  The query for those interested:

```
select P.Id as [Post Link], count(V.bountyAmount) as numAwarded
from Posts P
join Votes V
  on P.Id = V.PostId
where P.postTypeId = 2 --answers 
group by P.Id
  having count(V.bountyAmount) > 1 --multiple bounties
order by numAwarded desc
```